# Android EGLConfig has no properties

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am getting EGLConfig objects using eglChooseConfig on Android like this:

```
    ...
    int[] configSpec = new int[]
    {
        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };
    if (!lEgl.eglChooseConfig(lDisplay, configSpec, configs, configs.length, num_config))
    {
    ...
```

eglChooseConfig returns 19 EGLConfig objects.

I want to get properties from these objects like color depth for example.

The problem is that the EGLConfig class has no getters nor public members.
See [EGLConfig documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGLConfig).

Does anybody know how to get properties like color depth from an EGLConfig object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I had to use eglGetConfigAttrib like this:

```
    int[] lValue = new int[1];
    lEgl.eglGetConfigAttrib(lDisplay, configs[0],  EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE , lValue);
    Log.v("eglresult", "EGL_ALPHA_SIZE: " + lValue[0]);
```